# Whether the connection mode for dataset shared with external user is live or direct query?

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-dataset-external-org-share-about#considerations-and-limitations

> Live connect mode isn't currently supported for in-place dataset
> sharing. Power BI will need to change queries in the DirectQuery mode,
> which consumes resources on shared capacity or a Premium capacity.

Subsequently it also says:

> Users with appropriate permissions in the consumer tenant get live
> access to this dataset.

I am finding both the above are contradictory?

Comment: it's live access via DirectQuery (meaning local layer on the tabular model in the provider tenant), rather than live connection to that model. Seems similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-datasets-azure-analysis-services

Comment: So direct query will be made into the providers model? So it will consume shared capacity of consumer or provider tenant?

Comment: And What is the appropriate permission in the consumer tenant?